# BundleTransformer for less complaining "Could not find a factory, that creates an instance of the JavaScript engine"

Tags: asp.net, bundletransformer

If you upgrade from version 1 to version 2 of BundleTransformer you may get this message:

> Could not find a factory, that creates an instance of the JavaScript
>   engine with name `MsieJsEngine`.

Like me, you may not even have realized you've upgraded more than just a point release.

How to fix?

Answer (score 14):

#### Version 2 DOES NOT USE WEB.CONFIG for configuration anymore

So start by removing it and read the rest of this link

https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/How-to-upgrade-applications-to-version-2.X

---

Basically you will be doing the following:

- Removing existing web.config nodes for javscript engine
- Adding to someplace like global.asax some initialization code
- Install Nuget packages for the engines you want to use
- Make sure to add a `using` statement to be able to use extension methods (if you choose that way)

I ended up with something like this:

```
    using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core;
    using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie;
    using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8;

    ....

    public class JsEngineSwitcherConfig
    {
        public static void Configure(JsEngineSwitcher engineSwitcher)
        {
            engineSwitcher.EngineFactories
                .AddMsie(new MsieSettings
                {
                    UseEcmaScript5Polyfill = true,
                    UseJson2Library = true
                })
                .AddV8();

            engineSwitcher.DefaultEngineName = MsieJsEngine.EngineName;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the instructions, but my code is now breaking on BundleConfig

**var cssTransformer = new StyleTransformer();**

> In the `name` attribute of `/configuration/bundleTransformer/less/jsEngine` configuration element not specified a name of JavaScript engine.
>
> If you have not installed JavaScript engine, then for correct working
>   of this module is recommended to install one of the following NuGet
>   packages:    * JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie   *
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8   * JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore
>
> After package is installed, need set a name of JavaScript engine (for
>   example, `MsieJsEngine`) to the `name` attribute of
>   `/configuration/bundleTransformer/less/jsEngine` configuration
>   element.